# Can I see another sample of this program? I'm having difficulty in understanding it

Tags: java, c

```
int j = 0;              
while (j < A.length) {          
    i = j + 1;               
    while (i < A.length) {      
        if(A[i] < A[j])         
            //swap              
            int temp = A[i];        
            A[i] = A[j];
            A[j] = temp;            
        }                   
        i++;                
    }                   
    j++;        

}
```

a program that will output the number of swaps that will be executed for different array lengths as enumerated below:
a.  100
b.  1,000
c.  10,000
d.  100,000
e.  1,000,000

Comment: Why don't you just increment and report on a counter in the `swap` area of the code?

Comment: @Makoto I'm sorry I'm such a noob could I see an example cause my professor didn't taught us this

Comment: This is a `bubble sort` implementation. Google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
initiate counter (j)
 while j is less than length(A) -
   /* if this pair is out of order */
   if A[index-1] > A[index] then
     /* swap them and remember something changed */
     swap( A[index-1], A[index] )
     swapped = true
   end if
 end while
increment counter (j)
```

p.s your brackets are not matching are you missing a code segment?

Comment: oh I see ok ok thanks a lot @user2203521 yes it's incomplete

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking then it is important to note that *line indentation* is not semantically meaningful in Java (you need braces),

```
if(A[i] < A[j]) { // <-- Open brace         
  //swap              
  int temp = A[i];        
  A[i] = A[j];
  A[j] = temp;   
} // <-- Close brace
```